# I want to hise 'You did not select a file' error message in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

i made a registration form in codeigniter i want to hide the error ....'You did not select a file' because image filed is not mandatory in my  form...please help guys

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please look [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add your code to the question.

Comment: Need to see the registration form controller.